# Launching application automatically in iphone 4 os

Tags: iphone

I want to build an application that will be launched automatically on a particular date. Is there any way to do that in Iphone 4.0 OS. Actually I am building a sort of reminder that will send an sms for occasions like birthday, or other event. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible. You can't do it, you can't even bring an app into the foreground.

Look up push and local notifications. You can create an app that will send an sms-style local notification after a certain time. :)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Here is another link you might want to check out, as well: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/